# save active cell address in a variable vba

Tags: excel, vba, range

The following code is not storing the address of the selection in the variable sek, even when sek is declared as range. It is taking the value of the selected cell. I need to store the address of the cell as range not as string.

```
Range(zro(fm)).Select
Set sek = Selection
```

I tried to

```
set sek=Cells(application.address)
```

Could not get solution.
    I have written it like this

```
For fm = 1 To tmp
Range(zro(fm)).Select
Dim sek As Range: Set sek = Selection
Range(zro(fm + 1)).Select
Dim sel As Range: Set sel = Selection
    Sheets("extract").Cells((5 * a) + 1, fm).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Range("sek:sel"))
    Sheets("extract").Cells((5 * a) + 2, fm).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("sek:sel"))
Next
```

Comment: Basically i need to find a maximum in a range, i have address of range stored in the array.

Comment: maximum of what? can you show sample of you data and explain more what you need?

Comment: i am using 
Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Range) for getting max value.

Range can be ($B$4:$B$25), all these address are stored in an array

Comment: It seems that you mix up some concepts. `Dim sek as Range : Set sek = selection` does what you need, `sek` is an object variable which keeps references to range which was selected at the moment of setting.

Comment: Can you please reformulate your question using simple English? @ShashankNaik

Comment: sorry, started learning vb recently. Was not clear.

Comment: @KazJaw That didnt work. It is still reading it as values.

Comment: default property of `Range` is `.Value` therefore it is reading values. Use `sek.Address` to read its address

Comment: That reads it as string. I want it as range. Or sorry i didn't get what you meant. where should i add `sek.address`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
 For fm = 1 To tmp
    Range(zro(fm)).Select
    Dim sek As Range: Set sek = Selection
    Range(zro(fm + 1)).Select 
    Dim sel As Range: Set sel = Selection
        Sheets("extract").Cells((5 * a) + 1, fm).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Range(sek,sel))
        Sheets("extract").Cells((5 * a) + 2, fm).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(sek,sel))
    Next
```

Comment: I had made a mistake in the way range was defined. Thanks :)
You need not add that address (0,0)

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Also, there is no need to select the range in this code - just access the range property directly.

Comment: @ShashankNaik can you edit my code with your answer ?

Comment: I did, I think it needs some sort of approval

Answer (score 1):

What you need is

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(sek.Address & ":" & sel.Address))
```

This will combine the ranges.

Also you don't need to activate the range to assign it. You can replace

```
Range(zro(fm)).Select
Set sek = Selection
```

with

```
Set sek = Range(zro(fm))
```

Comment: Is there a way to save it as range? Because the max function that I'm using doesn't allow string references.

Comment: Are you trying to pass a range into a function as an argument?

Comment: yes, as edited in the qn, i need to get max and min in all ranges.

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(sek, sel))`